# Erro de sintaxe SQL ao atualizar um registro em C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Quando executo meu programa pra atualizar um registro, tenho o seguinte erro de sintaxe

[image: ![erro]

Porém minha sintaxe SQL esta correta:

```
string comando = "UPDATE cliente SET nome = '" + dto.Nome + "', SET email = '" + dto.Email + "' WHERE id = " + dto.Id;
```

Camada Apresentação:

```
namespace Projeto3Camadas
{
    public partial class frmCadastroCliente : Form
    {
        ClienteBLL bll = new ClienteBLL();
        ClienteDTO dto = new ClienteDTO();
        public frmCadastroCliente()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmCadastroCliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CarregarGrid();
        }

        //EVENTO INSERIR E ATUALIZAR
        private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //LOGICA QUE SE O ID DO CLIENTE FOR VAZIA, EFETUA A OPERAÇÃO DE INSERIR, SE NÃO EFETUA A AÇÃO DE ATUALIZAR
            dto.Nome = txtNome.Text;
            dto.Email = txtEmail.Text;

            if (txtId.Text == "")
            {
                bll.Inserir(dto);
            }
            else
            {
                dto.Id = int.Parse(txtId.Text);
                bll.Atualizar(dto);
            }

            CarregarGrid();
        }

        //CRIANDO UM METODO ESPESSIFICO PARA CARREGAR O GRID
        private void CarregarGrid()
        {
            gridClientes.DataSource = bll.SelecionarTodosClientes();
        }

        //AO CLICAR EM UM DETERMINADO CLIENTE, ELE VAI SELECIONAR E MOSTRAR NOS CAMPOS NA POSIÇÃO INDICADA: 
        private void gridClientes_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            txtId.Text = gridClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txtNome.Text = gridClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = gridClientes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Camada DAL:

```
namespace Projeto3Camadas.Code.DAL
{
    class AcessoBancoDados
    {
        //Atributos da classe Mysql
        private MySqlConnection conn;
        private DataTable data;
        private MySqlDataAdapter da;

        //Dados da conexao
        private string server = "localhost";
        private string user = "root";
        private string password = "";
        private string database = "dbclientes";

        //CONECTAR
        public void Conectar()
        {
            //Se a conexao estiver aberta, eu fecho ela antes de abrir uma nova conexão
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            //Guarda os dados da string de conexao
            string connStr = $"server = {server}; user = {user}; password = {password}; database = {database}; pooling = false";
            //string connStr = String.Format("server={0};user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, user, password, database);

            //Tratamento de exceção
            try
            {
                //Concretiza o objeto conn para conexao e passa por parametro a string de conexao connStr
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }       

        //EXECUTAR COMANDO SQL
        public void ExecutarcomandoSql(string comandoSql)
        {
            //Executa o comando passando por parametro a string digitada no comando sql
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(comandoSql, conn);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }

        //EXECUTAR LEITURA PREENCHE A TABALE E RETORNAR
        public DataTable RetDataTable(string sql)
        {
            //Retorno de um objeto Aqui so pode comando select
            //Concretisa o objeto data e da, em da é passado o sql e a conexao
            data = new DataTable();
            da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            //Preenche o objeto "da" com os daddos que estao no datatable "data"
            da.Fill(data);
            //Retorna o objeto "data" já preenchido
            return data;
        }

        //EXECUTAR E RETORNAR OS DADOS SELECIONADOS
        public MySqlDataReader RetDataReader(string sql)
        {
            //Retorna o objeto "MySqlDataReader" dado de um comando SELCET
            //concretisa a criação do objeto "comando"
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            //Objeto comando criado, basta executa-lo de modeo que ele retorne um objeto do tipo MySqlDataReader
            MySqlDataReader dr = comando.ExecuteReader();
            //Retorna o objeto dr ja preenchido
            return dr;
        }
    }
}
```

Camada DTO:

```
namespace Projeto3Camadas.Code.DTO
{
    class ClienteDTO
    {
        private int id;
        private string nome;
        private string email;

        public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
        public string Nome { get => nome; set => nome = value; }
        public string Email { get => email; set => email = value; }
    }
}
```

Camada BLL:

```
namespace Projeto3Camadas.Code.BLL
{
    class ClienteBLL
    {

        AcessoBancoDados bd = new AcessoBancoDados();

        public void Inserir(ClienteDTO dto)
        {
            //tratamento de erro para passar uma mensagem elegante para o usuario de modo que ele tenha ao menos a possibilidade de tentar resolver o erro ou ate mesmo ajudar o suporte a desvendafr o possivel errro 
            try
            {
                //Tratando de um possivel erro do usuario passar um nome com o uso de uma apostrofe ' pois o banco de dados pode confundir 
                string nome = dto.Nome.Replace("'", "''");
                //concretizando a instanciação do objeto, pois esse processo e matado no finally, sendo assim ao cadastrar dois usuarios ou mais simultaneamente, enfrentariamos um erro de objeto nao encontrado ou nao instanciado
                bd = new AcessoBancoDados();
                bd.Conectar();
                string comando = "INSERT INTO cliente(nome, email) VALUES('" + nome + "', '" + dto.Email + "')";
                bd.ExecutarcomandoSql(comando);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)//essa variavel recebe detalhes do erro 
            {
                //nesse caso irá aparecer para o usuario um mensagem mais elegante e descritiva sobre o erro, seguida dos detalhes tecnicos.
                throw new Exception( "Erro ao tentar inserir um usuario: DECRIÇÃO DO ERRO => " + ex.Message);
            }
            //Esse bloco sempre sera executado, dando ou nao dando erro.
            finally
            {
                //nesse caso e bem espessifico o seu uso, pois vai depender de cada aplicão, nesse caso estamos matando o processo do objeto db
                //um detalhe e que ao inserir um novo usuario de forma simuntanea, enfrentaremos um novo erro, pois o objeto bd nao esta instanciado.
                //SOLUÇÃO   - INSTANCIAR DENTRO DO BLOCO CACTH CONCRETIZANDO
                bd = null;
            } 
        }

        public void Atualizar(ClienteDTO dto)
        {
            try
            {
                string nome = dto.Nome.Replace("'", "''");
                bd = new AcessoBancoDados();
                bd.Conectar();
                string comando = "UPDATE cliente SET nome = '" + dto.Nome + "', SET email = '" + dto.Email + "' WHERE id = " + dto.Id;
                bd.ExecutarcomandoSql(comando);
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            { 
                throw new Exception("Erro ao tentar gravar usuario na banco de dados. DETALHES TECNICOS => " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                bd = null;
            }
        }
        public DataTable SelecionarTodosClientes()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                bd = new AcessoBancoDados();

                bd.Conectar();
                dt = bd.RetDataTable("SELECT * FROM cliente ORDER BY id DESC");
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {

                throw new Exception("Ero ao selecionar os usuarios no banco de dados. DETALHES TECNICO DO ERRO:" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            return dt;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando SQL está errado, quando usamos `UPDATE`, `SET` aparece uma única vez, e os campos e valores que está alterando separados por vírgula.

```
string comando = "UPDATE cliente SET nome = '" + dto.Nome + "', SET email = '" + dto.Email + "' WHERE id = " + dto.Id;
```

Neste comando basta um único `SET`, só remover o segundo antes do campo email:

```
string comando = "UPDATE cliente SET nome = '" + dto.Nome + "', email = '" + dto.Email + "' WHERE id = " + dto.Id;
```

Essa sintaxe vale para qualquer banco de dados, mas aqui a documentação do MySQL: [MySQL update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 7):

Seu código tem alguns problemas, mesmo que ele funcione, está errado. Não vou falar de todos em detalhes.

O uso errado exceções, só aconselho pesquisar o assunto aqui mesmo no site para começar fazer certo, você está piorando as exceções existentes.

Também pesquise sobre o uso de `int.Parse(txtId.Text)`, isto junto com exceção errada será um enorme problema, porque um erro de digitação do usuário se transformará em um erro de SQL. Pesquise aqui como resolver isso.

Essa classe `AcessoBancoDados` deveria implementar `IDisposable` para não gerar problemas, se não entende como fazer isso não crie uma classe assim, o código será extremamente vulnerável a falhas. Então se não arrumar isso é melhor escrever o código de acesso do banco de dados no seu próprio código. Nunca use coisas que você não sabe as consequências disto.

Mas a maior vulnerabilidade está no uso bastante errado de montar uma *query*, permitindo ataques de SQL Injection de forma muito fácil. Usando o padrão certo no C# fica mais difícil errar no SQL também:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE cliente SET nome = @nome, email = @email WHERE id = @id;", connection) {
    command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@id"].Value = dto.Id;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", dto.Nome);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", dto.Email);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/Update.cs).

Tirei a captura de exceção porque para fazer nada útil é melhor não capturar.

Em hipótese alguma continue usando SQL na forma que fez no código! Se continuar programando da forma como fez só não terá problemas por coincidência.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela orientação, e que sou iniciante, não sou programador ainda, essa lógica utilizada e de um curso que estou seguindo com meus estudos. Espero que me orientem melhor nos próximos módulos.

Comment: Sugiro abandonar esse curso, sério, vai te fazer mal.

Comment: Você poderia me recomendar algum, no qual eu não venha investir errado, já comprei alguns online e me arrependi também. Estou aceitando indicações de bons conteúdos, os ruins já tenho encontrado sozinho mesmo. Não quero sair gastando e sacrificando meu tempo pra aprender errado.

Comment: Não, não sei recomendar, porque eu procura formas estruturas de aprender, esse negócio de aprender sob demanda, fazer curso online não dá certo, quase tudo enganação, mesmo que não seja a intenção da pessoa. Certamente tem coisa boa, mas eu não os conheço. As pessoas perdem tempo porque querem cortar caminho, fazer o complexo antes de aprender o básico, é a economia bem cara.

Comment: E o que eu poderia está fazendo, ler a documentação técnica eu leio mais não entendo bem ainda. A faculdade não ensina de fato a programar, tem muitos livros baratos e caros, mas não tenho recomendações na qual me diga esse te ajuda. Poderia me da uma força?

Comment: Começa pelo básico, aprender programar antes de aprender tecnologia, antes de ler documentação, até pra entender a documentação, e ter capacidade de criar espírito crítico ao que vê, porque até documentação não está lá pra mostrar como se faz, está lá só pra exemplificar o mecanismo específico, e como muita gente não etende isso copia tudo errado. Eu vou fazer uma postagem um dia sobre isso, mas só quando eu tiver tempo pra fazer algo bem pensado, porque opinião todo mtem, eu preciso de algo que seja bem pensado.